# How to use LINQ/Lambda to shorten my C# snippet?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Ive written this piece of code and it works, but I would like to remove the 3 separate if statements and replace it entirely with LINQ. Is that possible?

Thank you!

```
public string CategoryTree
{
    get
    {
        var parentHandles = ParentTree.Select(c => c.handle).ToList();
        if (parentHandles.Contains(DbManagement.ParentSettings.MenuCategory))
            return DbManagement.ParentSettings.MenuCategory;
        if (parentHandles.Contains(DbManagement.ParentSettings.ProductCategory))
            return DbManagement.ParentSettings.ProductCategory;
        if (parentHandles.Contains(DbManagement.ParentSettings.TagsAdmin))
            return DbManagement.ParentSettings.TagsAdmin;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s is the type of `c.handle`?

Comment: What is type of `ParentTree` and Handle? is it `enum`?  what is type of `ParentSettings`?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by using LINQ instead of the obvious method?

Comment: Will the list contain only a type of category at given time? If yes, then this code can be shorten using LINQ.

Comment: Does `parentHandles` contain the values of `DbManagement.ParentSettings` in the order that you check for them in the code shown? If not, is there a way to sort them?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Since `CategoryTree` is `string`, it follows that `MenuCategory`, `ProductCategory` and `TagsAdmin` are `string` and this `parentHandles` must be `List<string>` and `c.handle` also `string`.

Comment: @NetMage Never assume code posted to a StackOverflow post actually compiles.

Comment: It seems the string happen to order according to preference, so just return `ParentTree.Select(c => c.handle).OrderBy(s => s).FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this - which is faster (`HashSet<T>` lookups are `O(1)`, whereas `List<T>.Contains` is `O(n)`):

(Assuming that `DbManagement.ParentSettings.MenuCategory` are `const` or `static` strings and not mutable instance properties)

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyList<String> _categories = new String[]
{
    DbManagement.ParentSettings.MenuCategory,
    DbManagement.ParentSettings.ProductCategory,
    DbManagement.ParentSettings.TagsAdmin
};

public string CategoryTree
{
    get
    {
        HashSet<String> handles = this.ParentTree
            .Select( c => c.handle )
            .ToHashSet();

        return _categories.FirstOrDefault( c => handles.Contains( c ) ) ?? "";
    }
}
```

If the order of elements in `DbManagement.ParentSettings` doesn't matter then this can be made even more succint by using `Intersect`:

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyList<String> _categories = new String[]
{
    DbManagement.ParentSettings.MenuCategory,
    DbManagement.ParentSettings.ProductCategory,
    DbManagement.ParentSettings.TagsAdmin
};

public string CategoryTree
{
    get
    {
        return this.ParentTree
            .Select( c => c.handle )
            .Intersect( _categories )
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
    }
}
```

And if `DbManagement.ParentSettings` isn't static and/or you're okay with having it reallocated on every call then you can reduce the whole thing down to a single Linq expression:

```
public string CategoryTree
{
    get
    {
        return this.ParentTree
            .Select( c => c.handle )
            .Intersect( new[] {}
                DbManagement.ParentSettings.MenuCategory,
                DbManagement.ParentSettings.ProductCategory,
                DbManagement.ParentSettings.TagsAdmin
            } )
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to the implementation of `Intersect`, if you did `_categories.Intersect(handles).FirstOrDefault()` it may be faster and will return the result by order. Of course, if you really needed to depend on either, you shouldn't use `Intersect`...`First`. I prefer your make your own `HashSet` approach (or its converse) as more trustworthy.

Comment: Very nice, but I wouldn't assume that it's faster. The cost of creating a `HashSet` may be higher than the cost of creating a `List` and performing three O(n) searches.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Correct. But in this particular case that would be a microoptimization (.NET is designed to handle short-lived complex-objects like dictionaries etc fine). `Intersect` is probably slower if this article from 2011 is anything to go by: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2011/06/16/linq-intersect-2-7x-faster-with-hashset/

Comment: Microoptimization, [the link](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/). :-)